# LInq querying collection inside collection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

my object contains a collection of collections . i like to get all child object ids and store it in a string array.

MainObject contains List of parent

Parent contains List of Child

Child properties  are (Id,Name)

how can i query MainObject and find all child ids and store it in string array using linq?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`:

```
var stringArray = MainObject.ListOfParent
                            .SelectMany(p => p.ListOfChildren
                                              .Select(c => c.Id.ToString()))
                            .ToArray()
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
var id =parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children).Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var arrayOfIds = MainObject.ListOfParents
                           .SelectMany(x => x.ListOfChildren)
                           .Select(x => x.Id)
                           .ToArray();
```